# JqueryUI Draggable - Auto resize parent container

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, jquery-ui-draggable

I have two divs, one within the other. The outer div (the container) is of arbitrary dimensions. The inner div is set to a specified dimension smaller than its container.

I have applied jquery draggable to the inner div and I'm looking to automatically resize its parent container when I drag the inner div past the outer edges of the container. How can I go about doing this?

I see a similar feature here on StackOverflow when asking a new question. The textarea for typing in a question has a div named 'grippie' which resizes the textarea. This is exactly the functionality I'm looking for, but with a div instead of a textarea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you go. Works both horizontally and vertically. See it in action at 
http://jsfiddle.net/evunh/1/

```
var i = $('#inner');
var o = $('#outer');
i.draggable({
    drag: function(event, ui) {
        if (i.position().top > o.height() - i.height()) {
            o.height(o.height() + 10);
        }
        if (i.position().left > o.width() - i.width()) {
            o.width(o.width() + 10);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: +! for a working demo; albeit it only deals with *one* of the *four* edges. But a good start. :)

Comment: @david Thomas, That's the concept behind drag auto re-size. The same can be done horizontally by using left position and width.

Comment: Well, yes: obviously. Which is why I up-voted. The comment was merely to suggest that you might be able to *go a little further,* to help the OP out. It wasn't, at least, *intended* as a criticism =)

Comment: @david Thomas, Ok i got you. Here you go. http://jsfiddle.net/evunh/1/. Also updated the code above. :-)

Comment: @Hussein, many thanks for going the extra mile. And +1 to the above-comment.

Comment: how to solve if the parent of the div which should be resized is of fixed dimensions - http://jsfiddle.net/LakYy/6/ ? [Similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23791878/jquery-ui-draggable-auto-resize-parent-containment) but solution without scroll, I need to get the scroll

Comment: This is perfect & a solution I've been looking for for quite a while, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **drag** function that comes with jquery draggable.
In the drag function you can just check if the edges of the inner div is outside of the container div's edges.

If thay are, increase the width or height of the container div.

You can use the position method that is native in jquery ui to check for positions of top,bottom,left and right of both div tags.

Here are links to the api for more detailed information about how these methods work.

1. [Draggable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/)->event->drag
2. [Position](http://jqueryui.com/demos/position/)