# JqueryUI Draggable - Auto resize parent container vertically only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, draggable

I have a div called 'content' that has a height set as auto.

I have appended a draggable child div using javascript to 'content'.

I have set the containment of the draggable div as the parent('content').

How can I make it so the outer div('content') will expand in height if I drag the draggable div down.

I know it needs a hack as the containment is stopping me dragging the inner div lower than the bottom of the outer div.

the 'content' div will have another div below it that will be positioned relative to it and will also move when the 'content' div is expanded vertically, so I have to have a predetermined height of the 'content' div before I start

any help greatly appreciated

I have set up a jsfiddle of it http://jsfiddle.net/F4bxA/3/

code to match

css

```
#content {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 215px;
  width: 600px;
  margin: auto;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 20px;
  min-height: 300px;
}
```

js

```
var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
newdiv.setAttribute('id', 'draggable');
newdiv.style.position = "absolute";
newdiv.style.top = "10px";
newdiv.style.left = "20px";
newdiv.style.border = '1px solid #000';
newdiv.style.display = 'inline-block';
newdiv.style.width = '75px';
newdiv.style.height = '75px';
newdiv.innerHTML = "draggable inner div";
document.getElementById("content").appendChild(newdiv);

$("#draggable").draggable({
     containment: "parent"   
});
```

html

```
<div id="content"></div>
```

**EDIT**

I have updated the jsfiddle to include the answer given below
http://jsfiddle.net/F4bxA/4/

now I need to contain the inner div on three sides, top, left and right.

any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with a lot of help from @patricia I have managed to solve this one :-)

heres a js fiddle of a working model http://jsfiddle.net/F4bxA/10/

and the code

```
var g = $('#draggable');
var o = $('#content');
g.draggable({
 constraint: "#content",
 drag: function (event, ui) {
    if (g.position().top > o.height() - g.height()) {
        o.height(o.height() + 5);
        return true;
    }
    if (g.position().top <= 0) {
        $(this).css('position', 'absolute');
        $(this).css('top', '1px');
        return false;

    } else if (g.position().left <= 0) {
        $(this).css('position', 'absolute');
        $(this).css('left', '1px');
        return false;
    } else if (g.position().left >= o.width() - g.width()) {
        var leftedge = (o.width() - g.width())-1;
        $(this).css('position', 'absolute');
        $(this).css('left', leftedge + 'px');
        return false;
    } else {
        g.draggable('option', 'revert', false);
    }
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Put your javascript like this:

```
var i = $('#draggable');
var o = $('#content');
i.draggable({
   drag: function (event, ui) {
      if (i.position().top > o.height() - i.height()) {
           o.height(o.height() + 10);
       }
       if (i.position().left > o.width() - i.width()) {
           o.width(o.width() + 10);
       }
   },
   containment: "parent"
});
```

Comment: If you don't want to change the width of the parent container just remove the second if.

Comment: it sort of works http://jsfiddle.net/F4bxA/5/ but you have to keep releasing the inner div and then grab it again to expand the height, is there any smoother way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

```
i.draggable({
 drag: function (event, ui) {
    if (i.position().top > o.height() - i.height()) {
        o.height(o.height() + 5);
        return true;
    }
    if(i.position().top <= 0){
        i.draggable( 'option',  'revert', true );
        return false;
    }else
    if(i.position().left <=0){
        i.draggable( 'option',  'revert', true );
        return false;
    }else
    if(i.position().left >=o.width() - i.width()){
        i.draggable( 'option',  'revert', true );
        return false;
    }else{
        i.draggable( 'option',  'revert', false );
    }
 }
```

});

This way I belive it's like you want :)

Here's the link to test: 
http://jsfiddle.net/F4bxA/6/

Comment: Patricia, its really close to what I need and thanks for the help, but the revert puts the inner div back to start position, I want it so the div cannot be dragged past the top left and right edges of the parent div.

Comment: I have updated the jsfiddle with a 75% working model but for some reason the inner box becomes 'non' draggable when its dragged past the right edge of the content div  http://jsfiddle.net/F4bxA/8/  any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think this question is the same as yours and has already an answer :)

[JqueryUI Draggable - Auto resize parent container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5022230/jqueryui-draggable-auto-resize-parent-container)

Comment: I have updated the OP to include this but still want containment on 3 sides