# Jquery ui draggable - auto resize parent containment

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am sorry my English is not that great. I would like my container element to resize to always contain its child elements.

Visit [jsfiddle.net/datakolay/LakYy/](http://jsfiddle.net/datakolay/LakYy/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var
        $document = $(document),
        $parent = $("#parent"),
        $container = $(".container", $parent),
        offset = $container.offset(),
        scrollbarSafety = 15; 

    $container.height($document.height() - offset.top - scrollbarSafety);

    $("#eleman,#eleman2")
            .draggable(
            {
                containment: $container,
                drag:
                    function(event, ui)
                    {
                        var
                            $draggee = $(this),
                            draggeePosition = $draggee.position(),

                            shouldHeight = draggeePosition.top + $draggee.height() + 15;

                        if($parent.height() < shouldHeight)
                        {
                            $parent.height(shouldHeight);
                        }

                        if($parent.height() > shouldHeight)
                        {
                            $parent.height(shouldHeight);
                        }

                    }
            }
        );    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to figure out the `shouldHeight` - essentially:

1. use a selector to get all the draggables
2. Get its height and compare it to what you currently have
3. Set the height.

Here's the meat of the how to:

```
        var shouldHeight = 0;

        $(".ui-draggable").each(function () {
            var draggeePosition = $(this).position();

            if (shouldHeight < draggeePosition.top + $(this).height() + 15) {
                shouldHeight = draggeePosition.top + $(this).height() + 15;
            }
        });
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LakYy/3/

Comment: how to deal if the parent is of fixed height & container's height should increase along with drag and hence, a scroll-bar should appear ? - http://jsfiddle.net/LakYy/6/

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/LakYy/5/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var
        $document = $(document),
        $parent = $("#parent"),
        $container = $(".container", $parent),
        offset = $container.offset(),
        scrollbarSafety = 15; 

    $container.height($document.height() - offset.top - scrollbarSafety);

    $("#eleman,#eleman2")
            .draggable(
            {
                containment: $container,
                drag:
                    function(event, ui)
                    {
                        var shouldHeight = getdraggablemaxheight();

                        if($parent.height() < shouldHeight)
                        {
                            $parent.height(shouldHeight);
                        }

                        if($parent.height() > shouldHeight)
                        {
                            $parent.height(shouldHeight);
                        }

                    }
            }
        );    
});

function getdraggablemaxheight() {
    var $parent = $("#parent"),
        $container = $(".container", $parent),
        maxheight = 0,
        currentheight = 0,
        currentposition;

    $container.children().each(function(index, element) {
        currentposition = $(element).position();
        currentheight = currentposition.top +  + $(element).height() + 15;
        if(currentheight > maxheight)
            maxheight = currentheight;
    });

    return maxheight;
```

Comment: how to deal if the parent is of fixed height & container's height should increase along with drag and hence, a scroll-bar should appear ? - http://jsfiddle.net/LakYy/6/

Answer (score 0):

Based on the solution by @caspian you may find this variation scales better with many draggables. Same thing really, but only finds the dom positions once per item:

```
        $(".ui-draggable").each(function () {
            var draggeeHeight = $(this).position().top + $(this).height() + 15;
            if (shouldHeight < draggeeHeight) {
                shouldHeight = draggeeHeight;
            };
        });

        if ($parent.height() != shouldHeight) {
            $parent.height(shouldHeight);
        }
```

I needed this as well for a project, here is the fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/genkilabs/WCw8E/2/

To @coding_idiot, what you are asking about will w the default behavior if you use `overflow-x: scroll;`